# find xml element in c#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm am trying to find a specific element in my list of citizens but the result is always null. Thanks in advance!
Here is the code I'm trying :

```
string filepath = "citizens.xml";
if (!File.Exists(filepath))
{
    CitizensList list = new CitizensList();
    Serializer.SerializeObject(filepath, list);
}

CitizensList citizens = Serializer.DeSerializeObject(filepath);
Console.WriteLine("The File {0} has this data", filepath);
citizens.print();


Console.WriteLine("Chose the name of the citizen from the console");        
string name = Console.ReadLine();

CitizensList search = new CitizensList();
var matching = search.Citizen.Find(p => p.FirstName==(name));
if (matching == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The Citizen doesn't exists.");
}
else
{
    Serializer.SerializeObject(filepath, citizens);
    citizens = Serializer.DeSerializeObject(filepath);
    search.print();
}
```

Here is my code for the insert of the data in the xml file that works correctly:

```
Console.WriteLine("Insert the data of the citizen");
                        Console.WriteLine("Name:");
                        string nm = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Surname:");
                        string sn = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Email:");
                        string email = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Phone:");
                        string no = Console.ReadLine();
                        Citizens citizen = new Citizens();
                        if (citizens.Citizen.Count == 0)
                            citizen.Id = 1;
                        else
                            citizen.Id = Convert.ToInt32(citizens.Citizen.Last<Citizens>().Id) + 1;
                        citizen.FirstName = nm;
                        citizen.Lastname = sn;
                        citizen.Email = email;
                        citizen.PhoneNr = no;
                        citizens.Citizen.Add(citizen);

                        Serializer.SerializeObject(filepath, citizens);
                        citizens = Serializer.DeSerializeObject(filepath);
                        citizens.print();
```

Comment: where's the data you are just initializing serializing and deserializing no data in your list

Comment: did you debug your program, if "citizens.xml" physically exists with any data?

Comment: yes in fact i previously added an insert method to insert the data in the xml file

Comment: Are you sure that what you are searching is a last name, because this is your search criteria `Citizen.Find(p => p.FirstName==(name));`. Also ensure you have the correct casing.

Comment: Cases: 01) Check XML file generated with respective data, 02) debug while deserializing, 03) check for casing in your linq.

Answer (score 2):

You are searching in `search`, a newly created (one can only assume) **empty** list.

```
var matching = search.Citizen.Find(p => p.FirstName==(name));
```

You *should* be searching in `citizens`, your list read from the file:

```
var matching = citizens.Citizen.Find(p => p.FirstName == name);
```